# What was Tom's position about Daisy in The Great Gatsby?

Tags: character, analysis, the-great-gatsby

After watching this movie twice, I'm still unsure if the movie was trying to say, whether Tom loves Daisy or not.

There are several mentions that are in conflict.

1. Tom was somewhere else when their daughter was born (Negative)
2. He is mad at Myrtle and slaps her when she is shouting Daisy's name in the party (Positive)
3. Tom dates Myrtle while claiming to love Daisy (Negative)
4. Catherine mentions that none of them (Tom & Myrtle) can't stand their spouses (Negative)
5. Tom starts to almost weep when Daisy said she never loved her (Positive)
6. He is just watching when Jay is kissing her wife and wants to speak to her alone (Negative)

And so many more.

So, what was his position about Daisy? Did he really love her or was he just playing a role to keep her out of Gatsby's reach?

Answer (score 4):

Yes. I think he did love her. As he said in his own words

> Daisy loved me ...when she married me...and she loves me now.
>
> She does. And what's more, I love Daisy too
>
> I love you, Daisy. Now, once in a while...I go off on a spree. I always come back. And in my heart
> I love her all the time.

The way I see it, all the "Negatives" was because of his personality and how he is. He's the prime example of "old money", He's very confident (Was always sure that Daisy will never leave him), self entitled and a person who don't care about what other feel or if they'll got hurt.

Here's a description to him and Daisy from the words of Nick Carraway:

> They were careless people, Tom and Daisy. They smashed up
> things and people...and then retreated back into their money and their...vast carelessness.

Comment: I do partially agree. He was confident, since Nick once said: _"His wife and mistress that were so secure..."_, which is a +1 to what you said. But I can't agree with what he said, since IMO he was some sort of a liar ( not as much as Gatsby).

Comment: Is he a lair though? What did he lie about? I mean he don't even bother to lie about or hide his affairs. Beside they stayed together, so his actions back up his words.